# Why this way of declaring function is obsolete in C++?

Tags: c++, c, function, syntax

this type of declaration of function is valid in `C` but why not in `C++`?

```
int sum(i,j)int i,j;
{
  return i+j;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to do it that way / what prompted the question?

Comment: FWIW, if C code like that comes to one of our code reviews, it's rejected immediately. ISO may feel the need to maintain backward compatibility but no-one is forced to allow that kind of cruft into their otherwise beautiful source code.

Comment: To clarify, although most C compilers still accept that syntax, it is obsolete in C as well.

Comment: To clarify more, although it's obsolete in C it is still in the standard. Most compilers accept it because most compilers tries to comply with the standard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because that old-style function definition declares no prototype. That is, the caller would not know what parameter types the function expects.

In C++, that's too much of a type safety miss. In particular, the FDIS says

> **Change:** In C++, the syntax for function definition excludes the "old-style" C function. In C, "old-style" syntax is allowed, but deprecated as "obsolescent."
>
> **Rationale:** Prototypes are essential to type safety.
>
> **Effect on original feature:** Deletion of semantically well-defined feature.
>
> **Difficulty of converting:** Syntactic transformation.
>
> **How widely used:** Common in old programs, but already known to be obsolescent.

Comment: Surely you *could* make the declarators after the closing paren a part of the function signature equivalent to `sum(int i, int j)` so that the old C code is still accepted, provided it specifies the type after the closing paren? Doesn't it make the reason for deprecation just parsing simplification? To me it looks more like the unification and simplification of the grammar, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You *could* also allow Pascal code inline with C++ code, but that doesn't mean you *should*. Old-style C declarations incur no benefit, so they were left out of C++.

Comment: @Jonathan why, yes, yes you could. There is no technical reason why you couldn't allow K&R declarations or inline Pascal code in C++, which means that type safety of the old style of the declaration is not the reason for deprecation as pointed out in the answer, no?

Comment: @AlexB you cannot make this work completely. If you try to, the next problem will be `void f(); void g() { f(0); } /* random C code */`. To make this work, you again need to say good-bye to type safety, and require `(void)` for empty parameter list. That's not going to be C++ anymore.

Comment: @litb, but isn't it the same as `extern "C" void f(); extern "C" void f(int i) { }`, which would be handled the same way as far as I can see? PS That is, current compilers will complain if these are in the same translation unit, or ignore it (obviously) if they aren't.

Comment: @Alex B: Surely you could not. The K&R-style prototype that corresponds to the questioner's sum function is `int sum();` If `sum` is used in some other file there is no way the compiler can know if `sum(1,2,3)` is valid or not. This syntax is allowed in C solely because of backward compatibility reasons, but is strongly deprecated. It is disallowed in C++ because type safety is a key goal in C++.

Comment: @David, but that's only because C does not retain argument types in the symbol name. A C++ declaration of `int foo(int a, int b)` will produce a symbol with different linkage in C (`foo` vs, for example, `__Z3fooii`), so I can't see a technical reason why `int foo(i,j) int i,j` must be treated any different.

Comment: K&R has no prototypes, and `int sum()` is a declaration without a prototype. The prototype declaration for the above function is `int sum(int i, int j);`. For `void f(i) short i; { }`, the prototype declaration is either `void f(int i);` or `void f(unsigned int i);`, depending on the platform (where `int` can store all values of `short`, it will be the former). Mixing both K&R and non-K&R definition styles is most confusing and so C++ is good to not support K&R.

Comment: @litb So you are saying that you *still* could make it technically work with platform-dependent prototypes (e.g. depending on platform ABI requirements, the compiler may emit different symbols for a given K&R declarations unless it's declared with C linkage), but that's just not worth the added complexity? I'm more confused whether you answer implies "it's impossible to make K&R style declaration type-safe" as opposed to "it's not worth supporting K&R declarations in C++".

Comment: @Alex I explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329956/why-this-way-of-declaring-function-is-obsolete-in-c/6330015#comment-7403233).

Comment: @litb (the linked comment was edited): OK, but that code does not specify types. To clear up the confusion, I was referring to the declaration format *with trailing type specifiers*. What I argue is that the declaration presented in OP's question is completely equivalent to a corresponding ANSI C declaration. C++ already changes the semantics of existing C declarations with regards to linkage, so why not make a C++ parser accept a subset of K&R declarations? The way I see it, there is no *technical* reason to disallow it, but no significant upside in allowing it either, hence the deprecation.

Comment: @Alex, the reason that this doesn't work is that the K&R stuff are definitions and not declarations, I think. And the OP only gave a definition. Pure declarations in K&R only provide the return type and not the argument types.

Comment: @Alex what my comment is meant to express, is that it would be totally useless to allow such style of definitions. What's the purpose? Most C code containing such definitions still wouldn't compile, because they contain calls like the one in my comment. Why not allow function definitions of the form `{ } f() void;`, and allow calling it with any (fixed) number and (fixed set of) argument types? There is probably no technical reason to disallow it (for some value of "technical reason"), we would just need to break up with a lot of type safety.

Comment: @Alex B "correct me if I'm wrong" -- You're wrong because adding K&R style declarations to C++ but with type checking would mean *totally different semantics* from K&R style declarations in C -- note that in C, a K&R style declaration has no effect at the *call site*, because it's not a prototype. Adding a feature that has familiar syntax but wildly different semantics is an *obviously* bad idea, not worth this lengthy debate. Note that *C* didn't deprecate K&R style declarations merely because of parsing complexity; that would have been a bad reason to break millions of lines of code.

Comment: @Alex B "I can't see a technical reason why" -- that doesn't mean that there isn't one. For instance, with no prototype in scope, `char c; foo(c)` widens the argument to `int`, but with `foo(char c)` in scope it doesn't.

Comment: @Alex B Actually, strike that last comment. The critical point is that, for type-safety, C++ does not allow calls without a prototype in scope, but old-style function definitions aren't prototypes; it isn't even possible to write a old-style *declaration* that includes the parameter types -- there's no syntax for that! So, the old style **had** to go in C++.

Answer (score 3):

Those are K&R style prototypes which were used in the original versions of C. The are now largely forgotten and have been replaced by ANSI prototypes:

```
int sum(int i, int j)
```

As others have stated, the K&R prototypes are problematic when used in function declarations because they do not include type information.  Presumably a compiler could parse a K&R function definition for type information but I bet no compiler ever did.

Comment: +1 and I like this one more because it's immediately clear what the types of the arguments are.

Comment: @cnicutar, with long parameter lists it is very difficult to make what parameter has what type. Also, you have to repeat twice the parameters.

Comment: @cnicutar because C++ code parsing is already complicated as it is, and C++11 adds yet another format of function declarations.

Comment: @Alex B, @Diego Sevilla Those are artificial reasons.

Comment: @Alex B, technically, C++11 only adds a way to define return types after the parameters. And even that is solely because of the needs of the parser.

Comment: @cnicutar yes, it is an artificial reason, but it's not a bad one. The last thing C++ needs is more complexity and C baggage.

Comment: @cnicutar All these comments miss the point. Type safety is vitally important in C++, but with old style definitions, parameter types aren't part of the function signature. Note that there's *no way* to include parameter types in old style declarations ... `int foo(x) int x;` with no subsequent `{` is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think because that reduces readability, and it has no advantage over what is accepted by C++.

Also this syntax complicates interface declarations. When K & R adopted this style, object-oriented and interface-based programming was not popular.

Answer (score 0):

Why should it be valid? C++ prefers type safety. You shouldn't be using that kind of function declaration in C, either: it's grossly outdated.

Comment: @Rup Because it doesn't declare a prototype -- it gives no information about the types of the parameters to the caller ... and that can't be changed, because that's the established semantics in C. Note that there isn't even a way to declare (vs. define) an old style function ... e.g., you can't put `int sum(i,j)int i,j;` in a header file ... without the subsequent `{`, it's a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Really, it should be obsolete everywhere because it's not as clear as:

```
int sum(int i, int j)
{
    return i+j;
}
```

...but I imagine it's missing from C++ especially because it looks a lot like (and could therefore be confused with) initialisation done in a constructor:

```
void MyClass::MyClass():myVar(5)
{

}
```

Comment: It is obsolete everywhere ... from the C99 standard: "The use of function deﬁnitions with separate parameter identiﬁer and declaration lists
(not prototype-format parameter type and identiﬁer declarators) is an obsolescent feature." And the main reason that it's missing from C++ is because parameter types are part of the function signature in C++ but old-style definitions aren't prototypes and there's no syntax for old-style function declarations to include parameter types.